# Formcontrol input disable

Tags: angular, typescript

necesito poner en disable mi input llamado desdeFechaCtrl, pero la propiedad disable no me la coge, anteriormente yo desactive otro formulario con lo siguiente:

```
desdeFechaCtrl: [{value: ' ', disabled: true}];
```

Pero tampoco me lo coge, necesito que este siempre desactivado

```
    formGroupConformidad: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    usuarioCtrl: new FormControl(),
    estadoCtrl: new FormControl("-1"),
    tipoCtrl: new FormControl("1"),
    desdeFechaCtrl: new FormControl(new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()-1))),
    hastaFechaCtrl: new FormControl(new Date())
    });
```

Si añado lo siguiente en el ngOnInit me desactiva todo el formulario, pero yo solamente quiero desactivar desdeFechaCtrl

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroupConformidad.disable();
  }
```

Comment: Has probado con `this.formGroupConformidad.controls.desdeFechaCrtl.disable()`?

Comment: @PabloLozano me funciono! pero ahora no obtengo el valor a ver como lo soluciono

Comment: Me parece que lo quieres no es deshabilitar, sino poner en modo "solo lectura"

Comment: Cierto, igualmente lo solucione de la siguiente manera `var hastaFechaValue = this.formGroupConformidad.get('hastaFechaCtrl').value`

Answer (score 0):

También puedes deshabilitar tu control usando:

```
this.tuFormGroup.get('tuFormControlName').disable();
```

Y para obtener todos los valores de tu form incluyendo aquellos que estén deshabilitados puedes usar:

```
const valores: any = Object.assign({}, this.tuFormGroup.getRawValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Para deshabilitar un control primero inicializa el FormGroup y una vez creado, le pides el control en particular que necesitas y lo deshabilitas.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeControl();
    this.formGroupConformidad.get('desdeFechaCtrl').disable();
  }

initializeControl() {
 formGroupConformidad: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    usuarioCtrl: new FormControl(),
    estadoCtrl: new FormControl("-1"),
    tipoCtrl: new FormControl("1"),
    desdeFechaCtrl: new FormControl(new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()-1))),
    hastaFechaCtrl: new FormControl(new Date())
    });
}
```